# Raspistill: use existing photo to define shutterspeed and iso of new photo

Tags: camera, c++

I have found that using `raspistill` with the `--timeout` option to significantly reduce the time before the camera takes a photo doesn't give the camera enough time to choose good exposure parameters (e.g. shutterspeed and iso).

My aim is to 'calibrate' the camera to the lighting conditions by taking a photo normally using `raspistill` (without the `--timeout`) and then use the values which `raspistill` chose for the shutter speed and iso for all future photos.

I am doing this inside a C++ program, using `system()` to call `raspistill`. I thought I could use [*exiftool*](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/cpp_exiftool/) (or similar) to extract the shutterspeed and iso from the exif data attached to the initial 'calibration' photo. However, the shutter speed in the exif data is recorded as a string representation of a fraction, e.g. '1/8'.

I have found this [patch for specifying shutterspeed as a fraction](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=59299) but it is quite old and doesn't seem to have been merged into the official code. I'm assuming there was a reason behind this. I am also hesitant about downloading and making *userland* because I read somewhere that you could end up with a dead pi.

Does anyone either

- know whether this patch is stable (and could you tell me how to integrate it?),
- know of a way to parse a cstring (`char*`) containing something like "1/8" to convert it to a value in microseconds (an `integer`, `double` or as a `string`),
- know of any other way to accomplish what I want?

Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot more hunting, I came up with the (C++11) snippet:

```
char* shutterSpeed_exif = "1/8"; // My starting point

// Convert fraction to microseconds
string shutterSpeed_frac = shutterSpeed_exif;
unsigned int idx = shutterSpeed_frac.find('/');
double numerator = stod(shutterSpeed_frac.substr(0,idx));
double denominator = stod(shutterSpeed_frac.substr(idx+1));
m_ShutterSpeed = (numerator / denominator) * 1000000; // Convert seconds to microseconds
```

I can now save this and pass it as an argument to `raspistill`.